# Appending arrays with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

Using NumPy, I want to create an n-by-2 array, by starting with an empty array, and adding on some 1-by-2 arrays.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
x = np.array([1, 2])
y = np.array([3, 4])
z = np.array([])
z = np.append(z, x)
z = np.append(z, y)
```

However, this gives me:

```
z = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

What I want is:

```
z = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `np.append(z,x, axis=1)`?

Comment: You are looking for `np.row_stack`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2])
y = np.array([3, 4])
z = np.append([x],[y], axis=0)

print(z)

>>> [[1 2]
     [3 4]]
```

No need to create the array before appending, `axis=0` will allow you to append row wise.

The previous works if `z` is not an `array` already. From then on you specify `z` as the original array and append the other `array` as such:

```
t = np.array([5, 6])
z = np.append(z,[t], axis=0)
print(z)

[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `np.array` :

```
>>> np.array((x,y))
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```